# How to pass function as an argument to another function, without running it automatically

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have 2 functions - one that is checking object status and the second one that is creating some connections when allowed. I'm trying to pass a function as an argument, but return that only when conditions will be correct. The issue is it is running anyway.

```
testList = []

def testObject(name, funct):
  if name == "testName":
    b = funct
    return name + str(b)
  else:
    return None

def someFunction(vector, opt, axis):
    testList.append("Something")
    return opt * axis
  
a = testObject("testName2", someFunction([0,0,0], 1, 6) )

print a
print testList
```

Output:

```
print a
print testList
None
['Something']
```

So even if "A" is current, testList should be empty.
Wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In python, arguments are evaluated before they are bound to the variable inside the function. That is, `someFunction([0,0,0], 1, 6)` gets evaluated before you even call your other function. You can always just pass a function, `someFunction` directly, here you want to partially apply the arguments. E.g. `lambda:someFunction([0,0,0], 1, 6)` being mindful that the free variables will be lexically scoped in the closure. Of course, you have to *call* the function, `b = funct()`

Comment: alternatively, you can make your function accept `def test object(name, funct, *args, **kwargs)` and pass them inside the main function manually `b = funct(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling your function when you're trying to pass it as a parameter. Instead of passing it as `someFunction(...)`, pass it as `someFunction`.

e.g.

```
a = testObject("testName2", someFunction )
```

instead of what you have. This will pass the function 'object', ready to be called. Then, inside the other function, simply do:

```
def testObject(name, funct):
  if name == "testName":
    b = funct([0,0,0], 1, 6)
```

I assume you'd want to pass the values as different arguments, as I assume these aren't constants, but this should be enough to guide you.

If you want to pass it in with arguments already set, I'd definitely give a look into [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.htmladd%20arguem), but keep in mind that it might become a bit messy.

For partial:

```
from functools import partial

partial_function = partial(someFunction, [0,0,0], 1, 6)
a = testObject("testName2", partial_function )

------
def testObject(name, funct):
  if name == "testName":
    b = funct()
```

Comment: The problem is that there are too many possible situations, and the only purpose of test_function is to check requirements and allow given arg_function permission.

That being said - I have 50+ functions creating different math nodes and each has some different input, outputs. 
Each time before creating new node I need to check if node with the same name do not exists, to avoid super long script I thought about function that will check that and run any given function with predefined parameters.

Comment: @KrzysztofMarcinowski I understand, although this is a bit outside of the scope of the question. Are you able to bring the if condition outside of the function? From the looks of it, it might be the best way to save you this headache.

Comment: Sure I can skip that, although it will give me additional 1000+ lines in total, that's not an issue - but was the reason I started to think if there is a better way.

Comment: I'd look into the partial function, then! :) 


Try this. I'll add it to the main comment.

Comment: Let me know if it works the way you want it to! @KrzysztofMarcinowski

Comment: @rmssoares does your `partial(someFunction([0,0,0], 1, 6))` mean `partial(someFunction, [0,0,0], 1, 6)`?

Comment: If you don't want to define parameters inside another function, just do: