# Why isn't it necessary for sig_msg() to have parameters?

Tags: python, api, parameters, request, get

I've seen it work, so it has to be right. Hope somebody can hint me:

1st question: `sig_msg()` is declared like it gets an request, but when its used, it doesn't even has parenthesis. how?

2nd question: how does `requests.get(request)` work? Is this in the documentation?

```py
class example(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        return None
        
    def sig_msg(self, request) -> requests.Request:
        body        = (request.body or b"").decode()
        url         = request.path_url.split("?")[0]
        request.headers.update( { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } )
        return request
        
        
    def call(self):
        payload = ''
        resp = requests.get(f"{self.APIpath}", params=payload, auth=self.sig_msg)
        return resp.json()
```

I got code and I don't know how it works.

Comment: With `auth=self.sig_msg` you pass only the function _name_ as an argument, you don't call the function from there. The implementation of `requests.get` will make a 'real' function call out of this name and add the required arguments at that point. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960521/how-to-pass-function-as-an-argument-to-another-function-without-running-it-auto for a comparable situation.

Comment: This is like most callback functions -- the arguments are supplied by the library that calls it, you don't supply them when you specify the callback.

Comment: ok **callback functions** is the keyword here. so lets see if i get it right: the requests.get() in the call function creates an object of the class requests.Request and names it request? This object gets handed over to sig_msg(). right?